# How to write SQOL IN query with two lists

Tags: apex, soql

I have two lists `allOppEvenements` and `tr` and now I should make query based on the these lists.

```
List<Event> allEvnts = new List<Event>();
allEvnts.addAll([select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Event_Color__c from Event 
                             where OwnerID =: PublicCalendarId AND WhatId IN :allOppEvenements OR :tr ]);
```

The above query is throwing error saying unexpected OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Event> allEvnts = new List<Event>();
allEvnts.addAll([select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Event_Color__c from Event 
                             where OwnerID =: PublicCalendarId AND( WhatId IN :allOppEvenements OR WhatId IN :tr )]);
```

You need to add whatId in both list.

Or if both list are same type then you can combine them in single set and use that as well.

Comment: unexpected token: ':'

Comment: @SrujanSujju check my updated answer. Add In in second or.

Answer (score 2):

You can make common set for these two lists and then a little bit change your query:

```
List<Event> allEvnts = new List<Event>();
Set<Id> resultSet = new Set<Id>(allOppEvenements);
resultSet.addAll(tr);
allEvnts.addAll([select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Event_Color__c from Event 
                             where OwnerID =: PublicCalendarId AND WhatId IN :resultSet]);
```